# In Magento 2, how to bypass cache for a custom block template extended from \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, swatches, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

Recently I customized category listing page to auto-select the color swatch in listing page when a color swatch is selected in the layered navigation filter.

Everything is working fine with cache disabled. If the cache is enabled, even though the filters are cleared, the previously selected swatches remain selected.

I know this is because the template is getting cached. I tried using `cacheable="false"` but no use. Can anyone please help me to resolve this, I just want a block not to be cached or any other better way to achieve this.

For your reference here is the piece of code I added in the "renderer.phtml" template. Added `"colorOptionId: '<?php echo $colorOptionId ?>'"` to pass it to swatch-renderer.js.

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer',
    'Magento_Swatches/js/catalog-add-to-cart',
    'priceBox'
], function ($) {
    var jsonConfig = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>;

    $('.swatch-opt-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>').SwatchRenderer({
        selectorProduct: '.product-item-details',
        colorOptionId: '<?php echo $colorOptionId ?>',
        colorOption: '<?php echo $color ?>',
        onlySwatches: true,
        enableControlLabel: false,
        numberToShow: <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getNumberSwatchesPerProduct() ?>,
        jsonConfig: jsonConfig,
        jsonSwatchConfig: <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonSwatchConfig() ?>,
        mediaCallback: '<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getMediaCallback() ?>'
    });

    var dataPriceBoxSelector = '[data-role=priceBox]',
        dataProductIdSelector = '[data-product-id=<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProduct()->getId()) ?>]',
        priceBoxes = $(dataPriceBoxSelector + dataProductIdSelector);

    priceBoxes.priceBox({
        'priceConfig': {
            priceFormat: jsonConfig.priceFormat,
            prices: jsonConfig.prices
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you added cacheable="false" and not cacheable=false, yes?

Comment: :) yes I added cacheable="false" not cacheable=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved using a different approach. As the logic I previously used is within the template, cache caused the problem. Now I injected the additional parameter into "jsonSwatchConfig" array and tried to use it within swatch-renderer.js.

In order to add a parameter in `jsonSwatchConfig`, you have to override `\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable.php`

To add that parameter within in the "div" override `swatch-renderer.js` and add that parameter within the function `_RenderSwatchOptions`. Here is the code sample demonstrating the same with a parameter called "customparam".

```
_RenderSwatchOptions: function (config, controlId) {
        var optionConfig = this.options.jsonSwatchConfig[config.id],
            optionClass = this.options.classes.optionClass,
            moreLimit = parseInt(this.options.numberToShow, 10),
            moreClass = this.options.classes.moreButton,
            moreText = this.options.moreButtonText,
            countAttributes = 0,
            html = '';

        if (!this.options.jsonSwatchConfig.hasOwnProperty(config.id)) {
            return '';
        }

        $.each(config.options, function () {
            var id,
                type,
                value,
                thumb,
                label,
                colorOptionId,
                attr;

            if (!optionConfig.hasOwnProperty(this.id)) {
                return '';
            }

            // Add more button
            if (moreLimit === countAttributes++) {
                html += '<a href="#" class="' + moreClass + '">' + moreText + '</a>';
            }

            id = this.id;
            type = parseInt(optionConfig[id].type, 10);
            value = optionConfig[id].hasOwnProperty('value') ? optionConfig[id].value : '';
            thumb = optionConfig[id].hasOwnProperty('thumb') ? optionConfig[id].thumb : '';
            customparam = optionConfig[id].hasOwnProperty('customparam ') ? optionConfig[id].customparam : '';
            label = this.label ? this.label : '';
            attr =
                ' id="' + controlId + '-item-' + id + '"' +
                ' custom-id="' + customparam + '"'+
                ' aria-checked="false"' +
                ' aria-describedby="' + controlId + '"' +
                ' tabindex="0"' +
                ' option-type="' + type + '"' +
                ' option-id="' + id + '"' +
                ' option-label="' + label + '"' +
                ' aria-label="' + label + '"' +
                ' option-tooltip-thumb="' + thumb + '"' +
                ' option-tooltip-value="' + value + '"' +
                ' role="option"';

            if (!this.hasOwnProperty('products') || this.products.length <= 0) {
                attr += ' option-empty="true"';
            }

            if (type === 0) {
                // Text
                html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' text" ' + attr + '>' + (value ? value : label) +
                    '</div>';
            } else if (type === 1) {
                // Color
                html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' color" ' + attr +
                    ' style="background: ' + value +
                    ' no-repeat center; background-size: initial;">' + '' +
                    '</div>';
            } else if (type === 2) {
                // Image
                html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' image" ' + attr +
                    ' style="background: url(' + value + ') no-repeat center; background-size: initial;">' + '' +
                    '</div>';
            } else if (type === 3) {
                // Clear
                html += '<div class="' + optionClass + '" ' + attr + '></div>';
            } else {
                // Default
                html += '<div class="' + optionClass + '" ' + attr + '>' + label + '</div>';
            }
        });

        return html;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still it is caching and also i am using fastly cache. In that when I purge the cache of specific product url then it is showing correct products and out of stock Sizes are crossed out. Without clearing the cache How to byPass the swatch renderer section.